# Load Image form PersistenceDataPath

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine

I'm making an Android app that should, in the beginning, load data from a MySQL database and some images from the server. After that, the user will be in the outside, so the app will work offline.

I made the code to save all the database data (it works) and the image from the server to ApplicationPersistenceDataPath (not working). I already search for how I should do that. The code I have does not throw any error. But, when I tried to display it on the app the image was blank. That's when I looked in the folder where the images are being stored, and I cannot open them.

This is the method I have to save the images:

```
IEnumerator loadBgImage(string url, string file_name)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
        {
            yield return www.Send();
            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                print("erro");
            }
            else
            {
                string savePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Application.persistentDataPath, file_name);
                if (!File.Exists(savePath))
                {
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(savePath, www.downloadHandler.text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the code to show the image file in a Image:

```
string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + nomeImagem;
imagem.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = LoadSprite(path);
```

This is the method called:

```
    private Sprite LoadSprite(string path)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) return null;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {            
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(900, 900, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
            texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Trilinear;
            texture.LoadImage(bytes);
            Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, 8, 8), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.0f), 1.0f);

        }
        return null;
    }
```

I really need to save the images first, and then display it offline. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Update**
After following the suggestions on @derHugo's answer, this is the code I have to save images:

```
IEnumerator loadBgImage(string url, string file_name)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
        {
            yield return www.Send();
            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                print("erro");
            }
            else
            {
                var savePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, file_name);
                var data = www.downloadHandler.data;
                using (var fs = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It works, but I still can't see the images when running the app. In the method to show the sprite I added the return of the created sprite.

**Second Update**

I follow again the suggestions of @derHugo, and I use rawImage instead of Image. And it's now working both on Unity editor and on Android device. This is the method I use:

```
private void LoadSprite(string path)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) print("erro");
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(900, 900, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
            texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Trilinear;
            texture.LoadImage(bytes);
            imagem.texture = texture;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally you should rather use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) like

```
var path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, FileName);
```

for system paths instead! It might be that your target device simply doesn't understand `/` as path seperator.

---

And either write also if the file exists already (maybe newer version? And you downloaded it already anyway) or you shouldn't even start the download if it exists already to save bandwidth.

---

I also think that `WriteAllText` isn't quite the correct solution for binary image data because [`www.downloadHandler.text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandler-text.html) is already

> interpreted as a UTF8 string

so since an image very probably has some bytes that are not representable in a UTF8 string you get corrupted data here!

You rather should directly use

```
www.downloadHandler.data
```

which returns the raw `byte[]` instead and than e.g. [`File.WriteAllBytes`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.File.WriteAllBytes.html) (only on UWP) or a proper [`FileStream`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6397249/7111561) for writing that `byte[]` to the file. Something like

```
var data = www.downloadHandler.data;
File.WriteAllBytes(path, data);
```

or

```
var data = www.downloadHandler.data;
using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

---

Than a white image in the scene usually means that the sprite is `null`.

If it's no typo than your `LoadSprite` *always* returns `null`. You forgot to return the created `sprite`

```
private Sprite LoadSprite(string path)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) return null;
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {            
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(900, 900, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Trilinear;
        texture.LoadImage(bytes);
        Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, 8, 8), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.0f), 1.0f);

        // You should return the sprite here!
        return sprite;
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

However note that a better way of loading also local images is actually [`UnityWebRequestTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-RetrievingTexture.html) as well. It also takes a local file path as URL and

> Using this class significantly reduces memory reallocation compared to downloading raw bytes and creating a texture manually in script. In addition, texture conversion will be performed on a worker thread.

But also

> Only JPG and PNG formats are supported.

but this shouldn't be a problem I guess since the `LoadImage` you used so far underlies the same limitation.

This would be asynchronous, however, so you'll have to wait for the texture in order to create the sprite. So instead of retuning the `Sprite` I would actually rather pass in the reference of the according `Image` component and directly replace its `sprite`. Something like

```
private IEnumerator LoadLocalTexture(string path, Image receivingImage)
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(path);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) 
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else 
    {
        var texture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)www.downloadHandler).texture;
        var sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, 8, 8), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.0f), 1.0f);

        receivingImage.sprite = sprite;
    }
}
```

If you are not bound to use actually `Sprites` I would always suggest to rather use [`RawImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage.html) components instead which can directly use `Texture2D` instead! And than do something like

```
private IEnumerator LoadLocalTexture(string path, RawImage receivingImage)
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(path);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) 
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else 
    {
        var texture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)www.downloadHandler).texture;

        receivingImage.texture = texture;
    }
}
```

but also

> Note : Keep in mind that using a RawImage creates an extra draw call with each RawImage present, so it's best to use it only for backgrounds or temporary visible graphics.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @derHugo. I did the changes you suggested and I can now open the image downloaded from the server. But I still see a white image when I try to load it on unity.

Comment: So we fixed the first part ;) can you checkout the bottom section I added if this fixes the local loading part?

Comment: Thank you very much, @derHugo. I followed your suggestion of using rawImage. I actually did not know the difference between image and rawImage. I was just trying to display the image in the App. I use the second method you suggested and it worked fine in Unity Editor, but not on the android device, I don't know why. But I tried then a method I had already seen and it is now working. I put that in my question. Thank's again!