# How to export Exchange Web Services Item to a *.eml file? (PHP)

Tags: php, exchangewebservices, php-ews

I'm developing a web interface for Exchange Web Services which should be able to save a mail item to eml format. I use PHP-EWS (https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews) to establish a connection to the Exchange Server.

I know how such a file looks like, so I could download a mail item and generate an eml template with the data.

But I found this post: [Save mail to msg file using EWS API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293129/save-mail-to-msg-file-using-ews-api). Colin talks about a mechanism which directly export a mail item into eml file. Is that possible in PHP, too?

Additionally I found another thing: https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/wiki/Email:-Set-Extended-MAPI-Properties. In this example somebody generates a mime content and set it to a new item. Is it possible to get the mime type (which looks like an eml file to me) for an existing item?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save a mail item in eml format you have to set the [IncludeMimeContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa580499%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) property to **true** in the [ItemShape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa565261%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) element of the [GetItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa566013%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) operation.
By doing so, you will get in the [GetItem response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa581575%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) a [MimeContent element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa580801%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx):

> The MimeContent element contains the native Multipurpose Internet Mail
>   Extensions (MIME) stream of an object that is represented in
>   base64Binary format.

As an example, consider the following code:

```
<?php

function __autoload($class_name) {
    $base_path = 'php-ews-master';
    $include_file = $base_path . '/' . str_replace('_', '/', $class_name) . '.php';
    return (file_exists($include_file) ? require_once $include_file : false);
}

/*
**  Adjust these variables before running the script!
*/
$server     = 'your_server';
$username   = 'your_user';
$password   = 'your_password';
$message_id = 'your_message_id';

$ews = new ExchangeWebServices($server, $username, $password);
//print_r($ews);

$request = new EWSType_GetItemType();

$request->ItemShape = new EWSType_ItemResponseShapeType();
$request->ItemShape->BaseShape = EWSType_DefaultShapeNamesType::ALL_PROPERTIES;
$request->ItemShape->IncludeMimeContent = true;

$request->ItemIds = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseItemIdsType();
$request->ItemIds->ItemId = new EWSType_ItemIdType();
$request->ItemIds->ItemId->Id = $message_id; 

$response = $ews->GetItem($request);
//echo '<pre>'.print_r($response, true).'</pre>';

if (($response->ResponseMessages->GetItemResponseMessage->ResponseCode == 'NoError') &&
    ($response->ResponseMessages->GetItemResponseMessage->ResponseClass == 'Success')) {
    file_put_contents("test.eml", base64_decode($response->ResponseMessages->GetItemResponseMessage->Items->Message->MimeContent->_));
}

?>
```