# Saving Microsoft office inbox items in to database from server level

Tags: outlook, ms-office

I am using a Microsoft office email for my business support tickets, I wanted store all my inbox emails in my database so that i can populate on my 'support dashboard' and manage the support system properly for my business model. Can anyone help me, how can i store the inbox emails with out installing the outlook in local machine. storing the emails in server level.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I'm assumed you are working on C# and SQLServer database. As I understand, you can use EWS or Microsoft [Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me%2Fpeople&version=beta) to achieve your needs. Also, I think that there are two ways to achieve it. Just for your reference.

1. Get and parse the message content through EWS or the Graph API, and then insert the Database. (It should be a very simple code.)
2. Fetching all mails in Inbox from Exchange Web Services Managed API and storing them as a .eml files. Then save the .eml files into Database using file streams.

Note: I think you should create a backend service project to store emails to the database on a regular basis.

Reference links:

[Reading Email from Exchange Server and Save It on SQL Database](https://forums.asp.net/t/1927649.aspx?Reading%20Email%20from%20Exchange%20Server%20and%20Save%20It%20on%20SQL%20Database)

[Storing them as a .eml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662855/fetching-all-mails-in-inbox-from-exchange-web-services-managed-api-and-storing-t)