# How to import/export msg files to/from Exchange mailbox with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

It seems that there is an easy way to import/export whole mailboxes content operating on PST files (see for example `New-MailboxExportRequest` and `New-MailboxImportRequest`) with PowerShell. One can even delete or move between folders particular messages in Exchange mailboxes. But I cannot find a way to **import/export Exchange mailbox items with PowerShell to MSG files**. Is that possible at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293129/save-mail-to-msg-file-using-ews-api

If you don't mind an EML file, which functions pretty much the same as a MSG file, this thread will definately help. It uses exchange web services. However you will have to translate it into powershell.

Answer (score 0):

MSG files are a outlook data format so there is no easy way to export with powershell.  There are probably some thrid party tools out there that might do what youa re looking for. There are ways from what I have read to export to .eml with exchange web services.  You also might give this a look: http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/exporting-and-uploading-mailbox-items.html