# Save Email as .eml with original email.body

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, mailmessage

I am saving my `Email` using `EWS` api using the following code. However, when I open the saved `.eml` and also in `.mht` format, it is in full text with formatting `<tags>`.

Is there a way to save the original `HTML` format of the `email.Body`, with the original look of it?

```
private static void saveEmailAsEML(EmailMessage email)
{
    {
        string to = "test@mail.com";
        string from = "test@mail.com";
        string subject = "test subject";
        string body = email.Body.();
        string emailDir = @"C:\\Temp\\Email";
        string msgName = @"email.eml";

        Console.WriteLine("Saving e-mail...");

        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
            client.PickupDirectoryLocation = emailDir;
            try
            {
                client.Send(msg);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: {0}",
                ex.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
                System.Environment.Exit(-1);
            }
        }

        var defaultMsgPath = new DirectoryInfo(emailDir).GetFiles()
          .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
          .First();
        var realMsgPath = Path.Combine(emailDir, msgName);

        try
        {
            File.Move(defaultMsgPath.FullName, realMsgPath);
            Console.WriteLine("Message saved.");
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File already exists. Overwrite it ? Y / N");

            var test = Console.ReadLine();

            if (test == "y" || test == "Y")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Overwriting existing file...");
                File.Delete(realMsgPath);
                File.Move(defaultMsgPath.FullName, realMsgPath);
                Console.WriteLine("Message saved.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exiting Program without saving file.");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So it contains the HTML then? It's nothing to do with what your saving. Whatever your opening this file with just using isn't interpreting the HTML.

Comment: Rename the file extension to .mht and open with IE. Does it look like you expected?

Comment: I have renamed it to `.mht` as well. Both formats are displaying in full text form instead of the original formatted `.html` with table formatting and images. My apologies, I may not have explained myself clearly. Let me edit my post.

Comment: You might want to try something from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293129/save-mail-to-msg-file-using-ews-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially reassembling the message from a few properties. Why not grab the whole MIME message (with all the headers, attachments etc.)?

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-export-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange